# Socket.io startup output kills Upstart script for node.js daemon

Tags: logging, node.js, daemon, socket.io, upstart

I have a Node script that uses Socket.io to broadcast messages to connected clients. I want to run it as a background process with an Upstart script. I can start the daemon with `sudo start my_server` and the process will start and run. However, the server is stopped immediately by Socket.io's standard output 'info - (Socket.io started)'.

This is executed, before the Socket.io configuration is read. Socket.io [documentation](http://labs.learnboost.com/socket.io/) shows that I can pass a 'log' option to the listen method to keep sys.log from sending output to stdout. But I can't seem to keep that initial 'info - (Socket.io started)' from being output. I even tried to comment out that call to logger in the module but it is cached.

Has anyone successfully created a node/socket.io daemon or suppressed socket.io's default output? Below is the code for my Upstart script and my node.js.

upstart script

```
description "node.js server"
author      "some@email.com"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
   export HOME="/username"

   exec sudo -u username sh -c "/usr/local/bin/node path/to/server.js >> /var/log/node.log 2?&1"
end script
```

server.js using socket.io

```
var http = require('http'),
url = require('url'),
fs = require('fs'),

//create server and attach socket io
server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
        res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
      }),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server, function(message){});

//configure socket.io logging so it is minimal
io.configure(function(){
io.set('log level', 1);
io.set('transports', [
    'websocket',
    'flashsocket',
    'htmlfile',
    'xhr-polling',
    'jsonp-polling'
    ]);
});

//instruct our server to listen to port 8080    
server.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('message', { eventType: "connected" });
});
```

I appreciate any answers or solution.

Comment: I think you should fill an issue at github, because even when I overrided the logger etc, that first message still got displayed on screen.

Answer (score 4):

That statement is in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js on line 117 for socket.io 0.7.9 (if you aren't using a global npm install then it'll be in wherever you've installed your npm modules). Open the file, go to line 117 and comment it out. Then clean the cache (`npm cache clean $HOME/.npm/socket.io`) and restart and it should be gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I wanted more of an elegant solution put sometimes if it works it works.

Comment: A more elegant solution is to report it on github so it goes away in the next release : )

Answer (score 1):

I received a message from [tedah](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/pull/380#issuecomment-1965853), a Socket.io contributor. His answer this problem was to pass options to the manager.js through the listener method as such…

```
options.logger = {
   info: self.emit.bind(self, 'info'),
   error: self.emit.bind(self, 'error'),
   warn: self.emit.bind(self, 'error'),
   debug: new Function()
 };

var io = socketIo.listen(port, options);
```

Where `options.logger.info` etc are bound to the container's (self) emit methods and `options.logger.debug` is ignored.